# Is there any way to simplify for this function?

Tags: python

This function works but needs simplifications. Is there any equation for this?

```
def picapp(a):
    x = (210*(a%4))
    if x == 0:
        x = 210*4
    if (a/4)%4 == 0:
        y = 275*5
    if (a/4)%4 >= 0.25  and (a/4)%4 <= 1:
        y = 275*2
    if (a/4)%4 >= 1.25  and (a/4)%4 <= 2:
        y = 275*3
    if (a/4)%4 >= 2.25  and (a/4)%4 <= 3:
        y = 275*4
    if (a/4)%4 >= 3.25  and (a/4)%4 <= 4:
        y = 275*5
    return (x, y)

picapp(32) ## Output- (840, 1375)
```

[Visualize my problem. Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPUM1.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `a` is an integer. A trivial way is to make it like this:

```
def picapp(a):
    x = (210*(a%4))
    if x == 0:
        x = 210*4
    if (a % 16) == 0:
        y = 275*5
    elif 1 <= (a % 16) <= 4:
        y = 275*2
    elif 5 <= (a % 16) <= 8:
        y = 275*3
    elif 9 <= (a % 16) <= 12:
        y = 275*4
    elif 13 <= (a % 16) <= 16:
        y = 275*5
    return (x, y)
```

But noticing your range check is very regular, we can further make it like this:

```
import math

def picapp(a):
    x = (210*(a%4)) or (210*4)
    multiple = 1+int(math.ceil((a % 16)/4))
    if multiple == 1:
        multiple = 5
    y = 275 * multiple
    return (x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a huge improvement in brevity but more readable and correct utilisation of **elif**:

```
def picapp(a):
    x = (210*(a%4))
    z = (a/4)%4
    if x == 0:
        x = 210*4
    if z == 0:
        y = 275*5
    elif 0.25 <= z <= 1:
        y = 275*2
    elif 1.25 <= z <= 2:
        y = 275*3
    elif 2.25 <= z <= 3:
        y = 275*4
    elif 3.25 <= 4:
        y = 275*5
    return (x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

yes but this is looks pointless but here is:

```
def picapp(a):
    x = (210*(a%4))
    y=275*int((a/4%4)+1.75)
    if x == 0:
        x = 210*4
    if (a/4)%4 == 0:
        y = 275*5
    return (x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bisect module for this job. Below is a sample code:

```
from bisect import bisect
def get_xy(A):
    x = [210*4, 210*1, 210*2, 210*3]
    y = [275*5, 275*2, 275*3, 275*4, 275*5]
    a = bisect([1, 2, 3, 4], A%4)
    b = bisect([0.25, 1.25, 2.25, 3.25], (A/4)%4)
    return (x[a], y[b])

'''
#Output:
get_xy(32)
(840, 1375)

get_xy(34)
(420, 550)

get_xy(37)
(210, 825)
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought of using ranges instead of calling the variable in many conditions. Also, extracting it to another function will make it cleaner.

```
def picapp(a):
    x = (210*(a%4))
    condition = (a/4)%4
    if x == 0:
        x = 210*4
    y = 210 * foo(condition)
    return (x, y)

def foo(a):
    if a == 0 or 3.25 <= a <= 4:
        return 5
    elif 0.25 <= a <= 1:
        return 2
    elif 1.25 <= a <= 2:
        return 3
    elif 2.25 <= a <= 3:
        return 4

print(picapp(32)) ## Output- (840, 1375)
```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
def costum_round(x):
    return round(x+0.25)

def init_x(a):
    return (210*(a%4)) if (210*(a%4)) != 0 else 210*4

def init_y(a):
    return 275*(costum_round((a/4)%4)+1) if (a/4)%4!=0 else 275*5

def picapp(a):
    return (init_x(a),init_y(a))
```